# How to highlight a specific area on a grid of panels

Tags: c#, foreach, panel, picturebox

Making a Panel filled form which I want a character (represented by a pictureBox) to move around on. When I click on the character's pictureBox I want an area to be highlighted that represents how far that character can move.

The image below is what I've managed so far but this is not quite what I want. The red bordered rectangle represents the pictureBox whilst the orange rectangles represent the highlighted area. Each black bordered rectangle is a panel.

[image: Current Highlighted area for a character with 2 movement]

A character moving to a panel on the diagonal should expend 2 movement so that if a character has 2 movement available the area below should be highlighted when the pictureBox is clicked on:

[image: Desired Highlighted area for a character with 2 movement]

I understand why my code highlights a square instead of the area I want but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated; below is the code I have written.

```
        foreach (Panel pan in grid)
        {
            if (pan.Left <= (selectedCharacter.PictureBox.Left + (selectedCharacter.Movement * 80)) 
                && pan.Left >= (selectedCharacter.PictureBox.Left - (selectedCharacter.Movement * 80)))
            {
                if (pan.Top <= (selectedCharacter.PictureBox.Top + (selectedCharacter.Movement * 100)) 
                    && pan.Top >= (selectedCharacter.PictureBox.Top - (selectedCharacter.Movement * 100)))
                {
                        pan.BackColor = selectedCharacter.PlayerHighlight;
                }
            }
        }
```

Feel free to ask questions if I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I came up with to address this issue. Feel free to comment if you can see an easier/different way to solve this.

```
Panel[] highlightedMovement = new Panel[1]; //creates an array of panels to be highlighted
highlightedMovement[0] = characterBeingHighlighted.CurrentPanel; //adds the panel the character is currently on to the array

int z = 1;

//highlights panels adjecent to those already highlighted for as many iterations as the character's movement stat
for (int i = 0; i < characterBeingHighlighted.Movement; i++)
{
    foreach (Panel highlightPanel in highlightedMovement)
    {
        //goes through all panels on the grid and adds them to the array if they are adjacent to any already in the array.
        foreach (Panel gridPanel in grid)
        {
            //checks if the panel is adjacent to any already in the array
            if ((gridPanel.Top == (highlightPanel.Top + 100) && gridPanel.Left == highlightPanel.Left) ||
                (gridPanel.Top == (highlightPanel.Top - 100) && gridPanel.Left == highlightPanel.Left) ||
                (gridPanel.Left == (highlightPanel.Left + 80) && gridPanel.Top == highlightPanel.Top) ||
                (gridPanel.Left == (highlightPanel.Left - 80) && gridPanel.Top == highlightPanel.Top))
            {
                //adds it to the array but only if it isn't already in the array
                if (!highlightedMovement.Contains(gridPanel))
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref highlightedMovement, highlightedMovement.Length + 1);
                    highlightedMovement[z] = gridPanel;
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//highlights all the panels in the array
foreach (Panel panel in highlightedMovement)
{
    panel.BackColor = characterBeingHighlighted.PlayerHighlight;
}
```